# will $("#someelementid").html('') still preserve space in DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an div with id `someelementid` that contains lot of tags or you can say long form in it. if i use jquery's method `$("#someelementid").html('')`
will it free the memory of that form in the ram?

Comment: Use `$("#someelementid").empty()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are internal functions in jQuery called `empty()` and `cleanData()` that detach everything jQuery knows about from DOM elements before freeing them. Those routines are called when you do something like overwriting or removing an element's contents with `.html()`, `.remove()` or `.empty()`.

So, to answer your question... yes, it will free up memory (in the client).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of the contents of this div use `$("#someelementbyid").empty();` if you want to free all the nodes it has in the DOM use `$("#someelementbyid").remove();`

Answer (score 0):

You should use .remove(), to remove elements from the dom in some element.
http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the implementation of the javascript/DOM engine. It can either free it up immediately, or wait for it to be garbage collected. It can even choose not to.

A reasonable guess is that it *would* be freed, but I wouldn't write code that counts on it.